# When is boost phoenix useful?

Tags: boost, c++11, boost-phoenix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the benefits of using Boost.Phoenix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013476/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-boost-phoenix)

So I started reading the documentation for boost phoenix.

However, I must admit that I don't quite understand the purpose of the library, especially since we have language support for lambdas in C++0x.

Could someone please explain or give me an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, not all C++ compilers support C++0x for a start.

Then there are some things that are not possible with C++0x but that are possible with phoenix. See this for instance: [C++0x lambdas with template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124579/c0x-lambdas-with-template-parameters).

Answer (score 15):

The Phoenix talk at BoostCon 2011 has a slide comparing Phoenix function objects with C++0x lambdas. See slide 24 [here](https://github.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/raw/master/mon/phoenix_v3.pdf).