# copy_if with different types

Tags: c++, c++14

Is there a modern way of expressing the intent to conditionally copy from a source container of a different type to a destination container if I know how to extract the matching type?

It is easier to pose the question as a code-example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {};
struct FooBar{
    bool is_valid;
    Foo foo;
};

std::vector<Foo> get_valid_foos(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars){
    std::vector<Foo> valid_foos;
    for(const auto& fbar : foobars){
        if(fbar.is_valid)
            valid_foos.push_back(fbar.foo);
    }
    return valid_foos;
}

std::vector<Foo> get_valid_foos_modern(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars){
    std::vector<Foo> valid_foos;
    std::copy_if(foobars.begin(), foobars.end(), std::back_inserter(valid_foos),
        [](const auto& foobar){
            return foobar.is_valid;
        });
    //?? std::copy requires input and output types to match
    return valid_foos;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/miPbfW

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23579832/1896169 . There is no `std::transform_if`, but if you are willing to use libraries, there are several libraries that can do this

Comment: Of course, `std::copy_if` will work just fine if the source type can be assigned to the target type.

Comment: @PeteBecker: With the proviso that if the assignment gives a warning, you'll get a template instantiation stack in your warning message. VS2017 produces about 50 lines for an int-to-float conversion. The "extraction function" could be as simple as `static_cast<float>( )`.

Comment: @MSalters -- yes, some compilers are horrible to work with. Especially when they decide that they know your requirements better than you do. Turn off stupid warnings!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/):

```
std::vector<Foo> get_valid_foos(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars) {
    return foobars
        | view::filter(&FooBar::is_valid)
        | view::transform(&FooBar::foo);
}
```

That's pretty expressive.

Comment: This is beautiful, why isn't this in the standard?

Comment: @arynaq There's work on adding something like this. See the [Ranges TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges)

Comment: Ah unfortunately no MSVC support from what I can see on the docs.

Comment: @arynaq If you use [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg), there's support for a limited version of Range V3

Comment: @arynaq It's likely that a lot of the Ranges TS will be in C++20.

Comment: Which is rather late TBH. The "View Template Library" by Martin Weiser and Gary Powell was presented at the First Workshop on C++ Template Metaprogramming, back in Oct 2000.

Comment: Hm. While you are at it, why not pass it in as a `std::span`, which should also be in C++20?

Comment: @Deduplicator range-v3 at least compiles in C++14 :-)

Comment: Is there any part of the guideline-support-library (which also contains `span`) not available for C++11 up?

Answer (score 7):

Like the other answer put forth, Ranges offer a very concise solution to this problem. We're still a few years out from C++20 being standardized though (and another few years before it becomes accessible in enterprise environments) so we need a C++17-compatible solution.

What you're looking for is a hypothetical `transform_if`, which was not included in the Standard Library for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23579922/5241642)

You have a couple of options.

The simplest is to just combine `std::copy_if` and `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<Foo> get_valid_foos_modern(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars){
    std::vector<FooBar> valid_foobars;
    std::copy_if(foobars.begin(), foobars.end(), std::back_inserter(valid_foobars), [](const auto& foobar){
        return foobar.is_valid;
    });
    std::vector<Foo> valid_foos;
    std::transform(valid_foobars.begin(), valid_foobars.end(), std::back_inserter(valid_foos), [](auto const& fooBar) {return fooBar.foo;});
    return valid_foos;
}
```

The downside to this approach is that it creates temporary `FooBar` objects for each object that is going to get transformed, which you may find undesirable. You could roll your own `transform_if` algorithm implementation:

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename Predicate, typename TransformFunc>
OutputIterator transform_if(
    InputIterator&& begin, 
    InputIterator&& end, 
    OutputIterator&& out, 
    Predicate&& predicate, 
    TransformFunc&& transformer
) {
    for(; begin != end; ++begin, ++out) {
        if(predicate(*begin))
            *out = transformer(*begin);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Which you'd then be able to use directly in your code:

```
std::vector<Foo> get_valid_foos_modern(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars){
    std::vector<Foo> valid_foos;
    transform_if(
        foobars.begin(), 
        foobars.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(valid_foos), 
        [](const auto& foobar) { return foobar.is_valid;},
        [](auto const& foobar) { return foobar.foo;}
    );
    return valid_foos;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not as nice as range-v3, you could use [Boost Range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html):

```
std::vector<Foo> get_valid_foos(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars) {
    std::vector<Foo> result;

    boost::push_back(
        result, foobars | boost::adaptors::filtered([](const FooBar& foobar) {
                    return foobar.is_valid;
                }) | boost::adaptors::transformed([](const FooBar& foobar) {
                    return foobar.foo;
                }));

    return result;
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KAeB3L6Q2oXcvhPw)

Answer (score 1):

A back insertor iterator `it` will try and `push_back` anything that is assigned to `it`.
Currently, you get an error because `it = foobar` is ill-formed. Indeed `vector_of_foo.push_back(foobar)` is ill-formed itself.

If only there was a way to *implicitly* convert a `FooBar` into a `Foo`... wait! There is! Well, the annoying thing is that it introduces a circular dependency between `Foo` and `FooBar`. Let us break it with CRTP!

```
template<class TFoo>
struct TFooBar
{
    bool is_valid;
    TFoo foo;
};
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(TFooBar<Foo> const& src) { *this = src.foo; }
};
using FooBar = TFooBar<Foo>;
```

Now, `std::back_inserter(foos) = FooBar{}` does what is expected. And `copy_if` will behave too!

```
auto get_valid_foos_modern(const std::vector<FooBar>& foobars){
    std::vector<Foo> result;
    std::copy_if(begin(foobars), end(foobars), std::back_inserter(result),
        [](const auto& foobar) {
            return foobar.is_valid;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a40aeca7a9a057b2

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a hypothetical <s>`std::transform_if`</s>, which is not available ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23579832/335858)).

A somewhat expensive work-around would be to `std::copy_if` into a temporary vector, followed by a `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<FooBar> foobars_with_valid_foos;
std::copy_if(
    foobars.begin()
,   foobars.end()
,   std::back_inserter(foobars_with_valid_foos)
,   [](const auto& foobar){
        return foobar.is_valid;
    }
);
std::vector<Foo> valid_foos;
std::transform(
    foobars_with_valid_foos.begin()
,   foobars_with_valid_foos.end()
,   std::back_inserter(valid_foos)
,   [](const auto& foobar){
        return foobar.foo;
    }
);
return valid_foos;
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/g/mS7Csf)

Comment: I have never seen this formatting style before.... I've never seen `,`s at the beginning of a line in a function call.

Comment: @Justin This style is [borrowed from SQL](https://hackernoon.com/winning-arguments-with-data-leading-with-commas-in-sql-672b3b81eac9).

Comment: temporary solution is slower

Comment: @AndreiR. Slower than what? Two of the other four solutions on the page use a temporary.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, ranges solution(filter + transform) doesn't use a temporary, and neither does trivial solution from OP's question

Comment: @AndreiR. That's what I call "premature optimization".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I believe simpler code working faster is called "elegant solution", rather than "premature optimization"

Comment: @AndreiR. Any talk about speed without profiling is premature optimization. Besides, elegance of two easy-to-read self-explanatory function calls is pretty tough to beat.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Container,
         typename In>
class MappedInsertIterator
    : public std::back_insert_iterator<Container>
{
protected:
    using Out = typename Container::value_type;
    using Transformer = std::function<Out(const In&)>;

public:
    MappedInsertIterator() = delete;

    template<typename F>
        requires std::is_invocable_r_v<Out, F, In>
    explicit MappedInsertIterator(Container& c, F&& fn);

    virtual ~MappedInsertIterator() = default;

public:
    auto operator*() -> MappedInsertIterator&;
    auto operator=(const auto& value) -> MappedInsertIterator&;

protected:
    Transformer m_fn;
};

template<typename Container, typename In>
template<typename F>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v<typename Container::value_type, F, In>
inline MappedInsertIterator<Container, In>::MappedInsertIterator(Container& c, F&& fn)
    : std::back_insert_iterator<Container>(c)
    , m_fn(std::forward<F>(fn))
{}

template<typename Container, typename In>
inline auto MappedInsertIterator<Container, In>::operator*() -> MappedInsertIterator&
{ return *this; }

template<typename Container, typename In>
auto MappedInsertIterator<Container, In>::operator=(const auto& value) -> MappedInsertIterator&
{
    std::back_insert_iterator<Container>::operator=(m_fn(value));
    return *this;
}


int main()
{
    struct Telemetry { float voltage; unsigned timestamp; };

    std::vector<Telemetry> items =
        {
            Telemetry { .voltage = 200, .timestamp = 101 }, // accepted
            Telemetry { .voltage = 250, .timestamp = 102 }, // accepted
            Telemetry { .voltage = 300, .timestamp = 203 }, // rejected
        };

    static auto predicate = [](const Telemetry& t){ return t.timestamp < 200; };
    static auto transform = [](const Telemetry& t){ return t.voltage; };

    std::vector<float> voltages;
    using iterator_t = MappedInsertIterator<decltype(voltages), Telemetry>;
    std::copy_if(items.cbegin(), items.cend(), iterator_t(voltages, transform), predicate);

    for (const auto& v : voltages)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```