# is there any way to apply if statement to all variables in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, variables

if statements are usually implemented as `if(variable > value)`
what if I have a number of variables and they all have an operation for example a decrement operation and I want that if the value of any of these variables reaches to 0 the program should replace it to 100. 
Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Your title mismatches with your description. One ask for [`std::all_of`/`std::any_of`/`std::none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), the other asks for a [transform_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579832/why-is-there-no-transform-if-in-the-c-standard-library)

Comment: One way is to store all th variables as an array, and then loop over the array

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that by ordinary `if` but if you have a container containing your values, you can use `std::transform` and the condition you want, to do the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,4 ,-7, 0 ,-9, 9};//The container of the values
    //the following line does every thing
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [](const int& i){return (i < 0)? 100:i; });
    //To display
    for(auto& el : vec)
        std::cout<< el << " ";

}
```

And this is another answer inspired by @user2962393 's answer

```
#include <iostream>

void cond(int & h){
    if( h < 0 )
        h=100;
}
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void set_100_if_cond(T& x, Ts&... xs) {
    (cond(x), ... , cond( xs ));
}

int main() {
    int var1 {50};
    int var2 {0};
    int var3 {-9};
    set_100_if_cond(var1, var2, var3);
    std::cout << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3;
}
```

Comment: You can do it in a single `if` if you use an implicit construction from an initializer list: see my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think the OP wants to iterate over each value and the change the values satisfying certain condition. But your code doesn't do that

Comment: That's a good point. And makes your answer elegant and appropriate. Have an upvote.

Comment: Nice solution. Vector could be replaced with an array: std::array<int, 6>.

Comment: @user2962393: Indeed it could, but the rule of thumb "use a `std::vector` unless you have a good reason not to" is a good rule of thumb, and having to type "6" is annoying. (And don't forget to vote accordingly; helps the community.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Array avoids dynamic memory allocation, and in my book that's often worth more than typing the annoying extra "6". Ideally the extra "6" would be be automatically synthesized. Maybe someday in the future.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thanks to C++17 CTAD, no size to provide: `std::array> a{1,4 ,-7, 0 ,-9, 9};

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 you can write

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
if (std::max({a, b, c, d, ..., z}) > value){
}
```

assuming of course all the variables `a` to `z` have the same type; you can cast them if not. The `...` is used here typographically; insert your actual variable names.

Answer (score 0):

If all items are in a container, you can use [std::any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of). Otherwise, you can wrap up pointers to them into a container and use the same algorithm. If you don't want to do that, you might just have to type it all out or get creative.

Answer (score 0):

> if any of these values reaches to 0 the program should replace it to 100.

One way to solve this kind of problem is by using variadic templates and recursion (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void set_100_if_0(T& x) {
   if (x == 0) x = 100;
}

template<typename T, typename... TT>
void set_100_if_0(T& x, TT&... xx) {
    set_100_if_0(x);
    set_100_if_0(xx...);
}

int main() {
    int foo = 42;
    int bar = 0;
    int baz = 99;
    set_100_if_0(foo, bar, baz);
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

The program will print 100.

> Is there a simple way to do that?

Nope. Nothing in C++ is simple.

Comment: IMHO your last paragraph is puerile and ruins an otherwise good answer.